# Get Processed Email Template

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4

How do I get the processed Template in Magento 2 ? In version Magento 1 it worked like this:

```
$email_template = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($templateId);
$email_template_variables = array();
$processedTemplate = $email_template->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables);
```

Answer (score 0):

the same method exists in m2 and i suggest you take a look on how it's used in the `vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Queue/TransportBuilder.php` class, inside the `prepareMessage()` method.

Basically, the implementation resides in the abstract class `vendor/magento/module-email/Model/AbstractTemplate.php` which does pretty much what the m1 implementation did, but i suggest you take a look and understand what is processed additionally.